# possibly incorrectly encoded, cuando quiero consumir datos

Tags: php, laravel, odbc

Estoy tratando de poder obtener información, (con el fin de brindar una Api), en el cual la obtengo usando `odbc_fetch_object`, pero no logro realizar una petición `GET` y me devuelva la información que necesito.
Los datos se consultan y se procesan en un `Controller`.

La base de datos donde se consulta es una tabla `.dbf`, utilizo `VisualFoxProDriver` para lograr la conexión.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Queries\ApiSQL;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function indexPersonal()
    {
        $ODBCdriver = $this->ODBCdriver;
        $ODBCuser = $this->ODBCuser;
        $ODBCpwd = $this->ODBCpwd;

        $query = new ApiSQL;

        $conID = odbc_pconnect($ODBCdriver, $ODBCuser, $ODBCpwd);

        define('personal', @odbc_exec($conID, $query->queryPersonal()));

        $jsonData = array();
        while ($array = odbc_fetch_object(personal)) {
            $jsonData[] = $array;
        }
        
        dd($jsonData);

        return response()->json($jsonData, 200);
    }
}
```

Esta es la información que obtengo de `dd($jsonData);`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando quiero obtener los datos sin hacer `dd($jsonData);`

Laravel me devuelve el siguente error (en el navegador ):

`InvalidArgumentException`
`Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded`

Si el `Controller` lo utilizo de la siguente manera, puedo obtener los datos correctamente, pero no me convence para nada porque tengo que escribir una linea por cada columna.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Queries\ApiSQL;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function indexPersonal()
    {
        $ODBCdriver = $this->ODBCdriver;
        $ODBCuser = $this->ODBCuser;
        $ODBCpwd = $this->ODBCpwd;

        $query = new ApiSQL;

        $conID = odbc_pconnect($ODBCdriver, $ODBCuser, $ODBCpwd);

        define('personal', @odbc_exec($conID, $query->queryPersonal()));

        while ($row = odbc_fetch_array(personal)) {
            $data[$row['id']] = array(
                'pers_codi' => utf8_encode($row['id']),
                'pers_lega' => utf8_encode($row['legajo']),
                'pers_nomb' => utf8_encode($row['name']),
                'pers_domi' => utf8_encode($row['domicilio']),
                'pers_loca' => utf8_encode($row['localidad']),
        );
        };
        return response()->json($data, 200);
    }
}
```

Este es el resueltado que obtengo en `Postman` del código

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaria poder utilizar la primera opción, pero no puedo dar en la tecla. Si tienen alguna pista, les agradecería.

Comment: ¿Y el archivo fuente que codificación tiene?

Comment: Es evidente que hay un problema en la codificación. La mejor solución es encontrar a qué nivel se encuentra el problema para solucionarlo de raíz. En mi respuesta a [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/59489/29967) he tratado de abordar situaciones como la tuya de una manera global. Es muy probable que en tu caso se resuelva aplicando utf-8 al objeto de la conexión.

Comment: Y si usas json_encode Y json_decode y evitas de usar utf-8 encode?
json_encode tiene varias modalidades para formatear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Las bases de datos de FoxPro (DBase) generalmente tienen una codificación ASCII (o similar) y `json_encode()` requiere que los datos estén en UTF-8, por eso obtienes el error.

No tienes que crear una línea para cada elemento del arreglo, solo necesitas una función que lo haga por ti:

```
// Envías un arreglo a la función 
function arr2utf8($arr) {
    // Recorres cada elemento para codificar su valor en utf8
    foreach($arr as $key => $val) {
        $arr[$key] = utf8_encode($val);
    }
    // Devuelves el arreglo codifificado
    return $arr;
}
```

Cuando necesites codificar el contenido de un arreglo, simplemente llamas a la función:

```
    while ($row = odbc_fetch_array(personal)) {
        // Codificas antes de comenzar a asignar
        $row = arr2utf8($row);
        $data[$row['id']] = array(
            // Asignas como lo haces normalmente
            'pers_codi' => $row['id'],
            'pers_lega' => $row['legajo'],
            'pers_nomb' => $row['name'],
            'pers_domi' => $row['domicilio'],
            'pers_loca' => $row['localidad'],
        );
    };
    // Esto ya no va a generar error
    return response()->json($data, 200);
```

Comment: Perfecto. Era muy simple, solamente iterando en el array y codificando cada elemento.
Con esto puedo obtener un array con objetos dentro.
Muchas gracias